# AS3 Error 5001: Does not relfect the locaiton of this file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

After exhausting all options found here in the message boards, I'm reaching out to see if anyone can help me understand why I keep getting a 5001 error.

On my Main.as Header I have:

```
package com.dustin.core
```

Which flash can find but when I publish and test this, the compiler is unable to locate Main.as for some reason.

My Flash settings and folder structure can be seen here:
[Click to View Flash Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gmeoe.jpg)

I have tried various combinations in an attempt to get this working correctly, even removing the package linkage entirely to no avail. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You document class says core.Main (image 2). Should be com.dustin.core.Main - that's the package of your Main. It does not matter that you specify ...com/dustin in your sourcepath, it doesn't magically change the package, it just means it will include the source files from that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fygo Answered this question:

> You document class says core.Main (image 2). Should be com.dustin.core.Main - that's the package of your Main. It does not matter that you specify ...com/dustin in your sourcepath, it doesn't magically change the package, it just means it will include the source files from that path. –  Fygo